# SQLite ResultSet getString SQLexception

Tags: java, sqlite, resultset

I am trying to print out individual rows of this column from a database but for some reason I am getting an out of bounds SQLException error. The column I am trying to pull data from has 16 rows and its only allowing me to pull row 1 but not row 2. What am I doing wrong exactly?

[image: Database]

```
public void calculatePriceButton() {
    try {
        String SQL = "SELECT BasePT FROM `" + PantoneNumberLabel.getText() + "`;";
        connection = SqlConnection.FormulaConnection();
        ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

            String YellowFomrula = rs.getString(1);
            String TwoYellowFomrula = rs.getString(2);// causing error
            System.out.println("Yellow :" + YellowFomrula);
            System.out.println("021 Yellow :" + TwoYellowFomrula);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

//error log

```
java.sql.SQLException: column 2 out of bounds [1,1]
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.checkCol(CoreResultSet.java:84)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.markCol(CoreResultSet.java:97)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getString(JDBC3ResultSet.java:430)
    at supremeinkcalcmk2.MainController.calculatePriceButton(MainController.java:261)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1767)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$259/59531175.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Since you're only requesting one column with your select statement and the numbering starts at 1, rs.getString(2) does not exist. Aren't you confusing columns with rows?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am trying to print out each row and have it assigned to a variable. `rs.getstring(1)` prints out the first row with `3.1`. I need to now print out the next row with the data `0`.

Comment: getString takes columnIndex and not rowIndex. This is why you're probably getting the exception.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you @matrixguy how can I do something similar with rowindex and without an array.

Comment: there is no method in ResultSet to get entire row value. you can get all the columns values and concatenate them , if you really need the whole row as string.

Comment: `at supremeinkcalcmk2.MainController.calculatePriceButton(MainController.java:261)` What is line 261 of MainController.java?

Comment: @code-apprentice `String TwoYellowFomrula = rs.getString(2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that there is no column in the current row with an index of 2. If you intend to get a value from the second row instead of the second column, you need to call `rs.next()`. In fact, you probably need to use a `while` loop to iterate over each row of the `ResultSet`. You will also need a `List` or array if you want to store the values for other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

getString(column_name) gives the value of the column you specify with resultset pointing at a row.

do this

```
while(rs.next()){
 String col=rs.getString("BasePT"); 
// gives you column value on each iteration
}
```

So if you want all the column values, either create an array/vector of Strings to store them.

Comment: What I am looking to do is create a bunch of strings to sort each row individually 
`String row1 = "3.1";`
`String row2 = "0";`

Comment: so either create an array and sort the array or sort them in the query and then use the resultset .  String SQL = "SELECT BasePT FROM `" + PantoneNumberLabel.getText() + "`order  by BasePT desc;";

Comment: @ssj3goku878 When you have variable names which end in a number, you should use a `List` or array instead.